# Meteor blaze how to override startup point?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to create our plugin / template.

My current filestructure:

```
/client/
-main.js 
/imports/startup/
-html.js
-index.js
```

Default file /client/main.html contain the head tags. I want to replace head tags to /imports/startup/ directory.

```
// /client/main.js
import '../imports/startup';

// /imports/startup/index.js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './index.html';

// /imports/startup/index.html
<head>
  <title>index_html</title>
</head>
```

I get error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './index.html'

Error screen:

[image]

That is my mistake?

Day 2:

I add to index.html body tags

```
// project_name/imports/startup/index.html
<head>
  <title>index_html</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>body_html</p>
</body>
```

Now I don't get error: Cannot find module './index.html' and I see on the page "body_html" note. But I don't see my titles inside head tags.

Is it posible **head** tags replace from **client** foldet to **imports** folder?

Answer (score 1):

You simply do not have any file called `index.html` in  the root of your directory.

Maybe you meant `index.js`?

Comment: That do you mean: root directory ~/project_name/ ?

Comment: Can you share with me your whole code? I can't figure out what is wrong exactly.

Comment: Can't access your project. I dont want to give my CC info. GitHub is better

Comment: Sir, please review the project you linked. It does not contain the files you talked about :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't detect the problem in the project. I tried renaming the different files to avoid naming conventions conflict. Noticed that there was a version constraint on blaze-html-templates and upgraded that succesfully. I can't help you any further

Comment: In the end I would advise you to follow this tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates. You are still in the early stages of your project so you can redo it. If you ever pin point the problem let me know. :)

Comment: I think here is the answer for my question. https://forums.meteor.com/t/1-4-head-html-location-fixed/30276/4